# How to get current system time in WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly

I am trying to profile WebAssembly functions. 
For the moment, I use performance.now() in Javascript code to profile them.

Given that you can use [Emscripten toolchain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm) to compile C++ code to WebAssembly, I assume you could compile to wasm a C++ program containing a function that gets the current system time in nanoseconds (standard library [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)). (Correct me if this is wrong)

Therefore, how to get current system time (nanoseconds) in WebAssembly?
(Using text format .wat and then compiling it to .wasm to be called in Javascript)